# Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.119.03/build/make.log for more

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, kernel

**ubuntu version: 20.04.4 LTS**

**uname -r : 5.15.0-41-generic**

**When I try to run "sudo apt upgrade". It executed with the following logs..**

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-compute-450:i386

  libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-decode-450:i386 libnvidia-encode-450

  libnvidia-encode-450:i386 libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450

  libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-gl-450:i386

  libnvidia-ifr1-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386

  linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-20.04

  linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 nvidia-compute-utils-450

  nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-driver-450 nvidia-kernel-common-450

  nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-utils-450 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up nvidia-dkms-450 (450.119.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...

update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

INFO:Enable nvidia

DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude

DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here

DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad

Removing old nvidia-450.119.03 DKMS files...


------------------------------

Deleting module version: 450.119.03

completely from the DKMS tree.

------------------------------

Done.

Loading new nvidia-450.119.03 DKMS files...

Building for 5.15.0-41-generic

Building for architecture x86_64

Building initial module for 5.15.0-41-generic

ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-450
.0.crash'

**Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.119.03/build/make.log for more information.**

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-450 (--configure):

installed nvidia-dkms-450 package post-installation script subprocess returned 

error exit status 10

Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic

I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda3

I: (UUID=1fc25e34-c79f-4aa7-8260-da68de226617)

I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Errors were encountered while processing:

 nvidia-dkms-450

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nvidia-450 and libnvidia-450 packages that have been kept back in Ubuntu 20.04 are transitional packages for nvidia-460 packages which in turn are transitional packages for nvidia-470. Updating manually to nvidia-driver-470 will update all the currently installed transitional nvidia packages.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470 nvidia-dkms-470
sudo reboot
```